# Java Decryption creating additional symbols

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

I'm writing a encryption and decryption code as follows

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EncryptFile
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
//Encrypt Mode
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\encryptedNewStringFile.txt"));
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("encKey".getBytes(), "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] getFileBytes = "writing a file using encryption ".getBytes();
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(getFileBytes);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        getFileBytes = "\n".getBytes();
        outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(getFileBytes);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        getFileBytes = "This is New Line 2 \nThis is NewLine 3".getBytes();
        outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(getFileBytes);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        outputStream.close();
//Decrypt Mode
        File curFile = new File("D:\\encryptedNewStringFile.txt");
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("encKey".getBytes(), "Blowfish");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        getFileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(curFile.toPath());
        outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(getFileBytes);
        InputStream bai = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputBytes);
        BufferedReader bfReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bai));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(bfReader);
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
        }
}
}
```

here i have a problem in output which is the printed output has some extra symbols (i.e question marks and box symbols)in it.
The output i received is
[image]

Any suggestions will be really helpful thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide code that we can copy and paste and run ourselves without any additional errors. Then include the output you get.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sure i've edited it now and there is the updated code

Comment: It needs a ``public static void main(String[] args)`` method to show us how to set this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the answers from @Artjom B. and @The 5th column mouse you get a file encryption program that will encrypt a file with Blowfish in **CBC mode**. The encryption and decryption is done in chunks so large files (up to some GB) could get encrypted and decrypted without "out of memory errors".

The key is generated randomly, and you should keep in mind - without knowledge of the key no decryption of the file is possible.

output:

```
file encryption with Blowfish CBC mode
used key (Base64): jsErS04so1NCC7Jmds6Grr+0tPkNoaj0hx/izLaW5H8=
result encryption: true
result decryption: true
```

**Security warning:** the code has no exception handling, no correct file handling (e.g. overwriting without notice) and is for educational purpose only:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Base64;

public class BlowfishCbcFileEncryption {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException,
            InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        System.out.println("file encryption with Blowfish CBC mode");

        String uncryptedFilename = "uncrypted.txt";
        String encryptedFilename = "encrypted.enc";
        String decryptedFilename = "decrypted.txt";

        // random blowfish 256 key
        byte[] key = new byte[32];
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        secureRandom.nextBytes(key);
        System.out.println("used key (Base64): " + base64Encoding(key));

        // random iv
        byte[] iv = new byte[8]; // blowfish iv is 8 bytes long
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);

        boolean result;
        result = encryptCbcFileBufferedCipherOutputStream(uncryptedFilename, encryptedFilename, key, iv);
        System.out.println("result encryption: " + result);
        result = decryptCbcFileBufferedCipherInputStream(encryptedFilename, decryptedFilename, key);
        System.out.println("result decryption: " + result);

    }

    public static boolean encryptCbcFileBufferedCipherOutputStream(String inputFilename, String outputFilename, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
            throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFilename);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename);
             CipherOutputStream encryptedOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher);) {
            out.write(iv);
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8096];
            int nread;
            while ((nread = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                encryptedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, nread);
            }
            encryptedOutputStream.flush();
        }
        if (new File(outputFilename).exists()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean decryptCbcFileBufferedCipherInputStream(String inputFilename, String outputFilename, byte[] key) throws
            IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        byte[] iv = new byte[8]; // blowfish iv is 8 bytes long
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFilename); // i don't care about the path as all is local
             CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename)) // i don't care about the path as all is local
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            in.read(iv);
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            int nread;
            while ((nread = cipherInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, nread);
            }
            out.flush();
        }
        if (new File(outputFilename).exists()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static String base64Encoding(byte[] input) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
```

is equivalent to

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

which means that each time you call `cipher.doFinal` additional padding is produced.

In order to write a file without intermittent padding, you should be using

```
outputBytes = cipher.update(getFileBytes);
```

and use `cipher.doFinal` only when writing the last time to the file. Then you will be able to use PKCS5Padding instead of NoPadding during decryption in order to remove the valid padding at the end automatically.

---

Security considerations:

- ECB mode is bad and should not be used. There are only very few use cases where this makes sense to use. At least use CBC mode with a randomly generated IV. The IV doesn't need to be secret but only unpredictable. We usually prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption. Since it has always a predefined length, this is easy to do.
- Use an authenticated mode of operation like GCM or use a message authentication code like HMAC-SHA256 in order to detect and react to (malicious) manipulation of the ciphertext.
- Blowfish should not be used today. Although it has no direct vulnerability, its small block size may open you up to different protocol based vulnerabilities. It would be advisable to use a block cipher with a block size of 128-bit. AES comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks @Artjom B for your valuable reply

Answer (score 2):

Each time you convert string into the byte array, you use default file encoding from your VM properties which is not UTF-8.

So, to fix this issue you have two options: to define the default encoding in java system properties:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

or add the charset encoding by each converting of strings into bytes:

```
"writing a file using encryption ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: While char-encoding is often an issue for variable data, for this program it is not, and if it were changing the sysprop _after_ the JVM is started would not help.